# Vue.js - dynamically applying method on input fields handlers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using *Vue.js* and I'm new to it. I'm using v-for to dynamically create `<input>` tags. Also I'm using v-model and v-bind which works as I would like.

But I'm also trying to apply different method to each individual input field. I'm trying something like `@input="event.methodToApply"` Those method are applying regex to the input field value. Not important for the problem I think. But I dont know how to apply different method on each field?

or if its possible give a parameter to the method so I can solve the problem inside the method?

```
<div class="case" v-for="event in this.myEvents">
    <input
        v-model="event.value"
        @input="event.methodToApply"  <-- this is how I would approach it but it obviously does not work
        type="text"
        v-bind:title="event.name"
        name="performance"
        class="form-row-right-part-first-element"
    />
</div>
```

And my data

```
myEvents: [
    { id: "event-1", name: "event one", value: "20", methodToApply: "formatEventOne" },
    { id: "event-2", name: "event two", value: "20", methodToApply: "formatEventTwo" },
    { id: "event-3", name: "event two", value: "20", methodToApply: "formatEventThree" },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the method name to a method called `call` :

```
@input="call(event.methodToApply)"
```

inside your methods :

```
methods:{
  call(methodName){
    this[methodNam]();
   },
 formatEventOne(){
...
},
formatEventTwo(){
...
}
formatEventThree(){
...
}
...
}
```

Comment: That does the trick, thank you! Also is it the only solution or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: i think `@input="this[event.methodToApply]()"` should work but i'm not sure or `event.methodToApply()`

Answer (score 0):

In vue you can access the `event` value with `$event`, in addition you can use an index in a `v-for="(item, index) in items"` then you can simply reference your method from an array of methods instead of keeping everything on the same object, unless of course you want to...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways you can achieve it:

`const myFuncLocal = () => { ... } // (or = function() {...})`

Now you can apply it like this:

`{ ..., methodToApply: myFuncLocal }`

You can also define a funciton in your `methods` properties, then you'll reference it thorught `this.` like you normally do

`{ ..., methodToApply: this.myFuncMethod }`

If you want to call it with a specific parameter you can wrap the function

`{ ..., methodToApply: () => myFuncLocal(param) }`

If your assigned function accepts a parameter it will automatically get passed to it if you call it like this for example `@click="event.methodToApply(event.value)"`